# \center is centering, but only at the top of the page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, titles

For an article, I'm trying to center my name and address, but `\center` is putting the relevant info at the very top of the page before the title instead of where I want it, after the title.
How can get `\center` to center where I want it to?

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `\begin{centering}Your Name\\ Your Address\end{centering}`.

However, that isn't good style because you mix formatting and content.

Instead maybe you can use `\author{Your Name\\Your Address}` and `\maketitle`.

You could also check for answers here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you will be interested by this skeleton of a LaTeX file. Basically I just extended @whoplisp's answer into a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\author{My name\\My address}
\title{The title of my article}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{A section}
Some text

\end{document}
```

Furthermore, you should note that `center` is an environment, used as `\begin{center}Some text\end{center}`, while `\centering` is a declaration, used to center whichever group it is in. It is for instance very often used in figures: `\begin{figure}\centering\caption{This is the caption}\includegraphics{file}\end{figure}`.